# TypeScript Type is missing the following properties

Tags: typescript, react-router

I am implementing a React Router and need to pass some parameters from the url path to a function.

My function expects parameters of the following type:

```
interface PathParams {
  appTypeId: string | null
  submissionId: string | null
}

async function getSubmission(params: PathParams) {
  const submissionExists = await getSubmissionExists(params)
  return submissionExists
}
```

In the implementation of my router. I pass the params as React Router docs recommend.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <AppLayout />,
    id: 'root',
    loader: () => defaulNewAPIs(),
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
        path: '/:appTypeId?/:submissionId?',
        loader: ({ params }) => getSubmission(params),
      },
    ],
  },
])
```

The problem I am having is with the params object that I am passing to my function.
The error reads:

```
Argument of type 'Params<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'.
  Type 'Params<string>' is missing the following properties from type 'PathParams': appTypeId, submissionId
```

I am not really sure how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The [params](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/fdadc703f97d2feda562f4365f9fbd2ed5d6f4a9/packages/router/utils.ts#L369C1-L374C3) only extend `string` type and are effectively optional. They are not nullable.

> ```
> /**
>  * The parameters that were parsed from the URL path.
>  */
> export type Params<Key extends string = string> = {
>   readonly [key in Key]: string | undefined;
> };
> ```

```js
interface PathParams {
  appTypeId?: string;
  submissionId?: string;
}

async function getSubmission(params: PathParams) {
  const submissionExists = await getSubmissionExists(params)
  return submissionExists
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this Type declaration imply that `appTypeId` and `submissionId` can be undefined? `getSubmission` will fail if either of those properties are not strings.

Comment: @tdammon Yes, but this answer is based on the code you provided here where you pass the params through to the `getSubmission` function and there is not any mention of the constraint. This seems closely related to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77901404/8690857) of your other post/question that I answered prior to seeing this one. If `getSubmissionExists` requires both properties to exist then the code should check for this prior to calling it.

Comment: @tdammon In other words, make the properties non-optional and do the check before calling `getSubmissionExists`, or you can adjust `getSubmissionExists` to make them optional and the check is done internally. Does this make sense?