# React Router - only call loader function if path params exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am implementing the new React Router. I am using loader functions to fetch data depending on which element is being loaded.

What I want to happen is regardless of the route some apis should be called. If the url is a certain route then certain additional APIs should be called.

The problem I am having is that the url path parameters are optional.

In my implementation below when the user visits `"/"` only `defaulNewAPIs` should run. The issue is since those path parameters are optional both loader functions run. `getSubmission` gets called with `null` params.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <AppLayout />,
    id: 'root',
    loader: () => defaulNewAPIs(),
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
        path: '/:appTypeId?/:submissionId?',
        loader: ({ params }) => getSubmission(params),
      },
    ],
  },
])
```

The reason I need those params to be optional is because my `AppLayout` component conditionally renders a header if those params are present.

```
const AppLayout: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ msalContext }: AppProps) => {
  const { appTypeId } = useParams()
  const currentUser = { name: msalContext.accounts[0].name }

  return (
    <>
      {!appTypeId && (
        <AppHeader
          appName="REFERRALS"
          currentUser={currentUser}
          notificationNumber="4"
        />
      )}
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route loaders are always called when the route loads and they are passed the route params, so you can check they exist prior to applying additional logic.

Example:

```js
type ReferralParams = {
  appTypeId?: string;
  submissionId?: string;
};
```

```
{
  element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
  path: '/:appTypeId?/:submissionId?',
  loader: ({ params }) => {
    const { appTypeId, submissionId } = params as ReferralParams;
    if (appTypeId && submissionId) {
      return getSubmission(params);
    }
    return null;
  },
},
```